# Ошибка при запуске airodump-ng: ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Operation not supported

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

Проверка безопасности, после команды >sudo airodump-ng  -c 6 -w cap enp3s0
" получил следующее -

> ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Operation not supported

ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211,
ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead.  Make
sure RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start enp3s0 <#>'
Sysfs injection support was not found eith
 я не совсем понимаю , как активировать данную иньекцию и нужно ли это ...
в конце концов сижу из под  Ubuntu , может стоит КалиЛинкус юзать 
спасибо

Comment: `enp3s0` звучит как имя обычного Ethernet'овского адаптера... это точно вафля? и при чём тут vim?

Comment: Через SSH дергаете airodump? У меня было такое когда по SSH дергал, когда локально то норм работает